# Авторизация на сервере PHP с помощью VueJS

Tags: php, vue.js, авторизация, jwt, фреймворк

Доброго всем времени суток.

Немного удалюсь от самого вопроса, чтобы было более понятно.
У меня имеется модульный самописный PHP фреймворк на базе которого построено несколько сложных CRM и более простых сайтов визиток, который отлично умеет работать с API (get, post, put запросы и т.д).

Что на данный момент мне необходимо? Я хочу подружить backend с VueJS, а именно создать SPA приложение используя бекенд своего фреймворка, и если речь идет о простых задачах, к примеру вытащить текст (пусть это будет запись блога) из базы данных и вывести её через Vue на определенной странице, то в этом не возникает проблемы, собственно как и в построении всей остальной логики сайта, но проблема возникает лишь в одном - авторизация и разделение по группам (авторизированный пользователь, гость, администратор и т.д). Я не понимаю способов авторизации (сервер backend и сайт на Vue на одном сервере / железе / IP).
Как можно реализовать авторизацию на PHP/VueJS, чтобы можно было динамически менять контент? То есть, самый простой пример - у нас есть две кнопки "вход / регистрация", после входа PHP сервер должен  отдавать определенный контент, скажем те же записи блога на главной странице. На стороне backen есть три способа передачи данных (отправка запроса от сервера к серверу, отправка данных запроса по ключу и отправка данных авторизированным по сессии пользователям). Я слышал и много читал про JWT, но так и не понял как работать с токенами. Я был бы очень благодарен за простой пример на PHP + Vue, либо за детальное разъяснение, заранее спасибо.

P.S - в Laravel существует похожая связка Vue + PHP, но в самом принципе работы я так и не разобрался.

Comment: Если сложно с токенами, то начните с auth basic. Нет ничего проще, чем передавать логин и пароль в заголовке запроса

Comment: А в чём сложность? Есть форма входа, есть обработчик входа. При входе отдаёшь юзеру токен и записываешь куда-нибудь. При попытке отправить запрос к движку автоматически подставляешь в headers токен (например, через Axios интерцепторы). В движке сверяешь токены: если токен действительный и правильный - пропускаешь, нет - "401, иди отсюда". Есть ещё рефреш токен, который обновляет основной токен, когда основной послал с 401. Это так, если очень грубо, то как всё примерно работает.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar правильно ли я вас понимаю, что API должен "видеть" заголовок запроса от пользователя? Если это так, то каким способом можно хранить заголовок у пользователя?

Comment: @Zerxa да, полученные токены хранятся у пользователя. Использовать LocalStorage можно (Vuex + vuex-presistable в Вашем случае). Подставлять заголовок можно через интерцепторы, чтобы не ручками каждый раз (у Axios есть точно)

Comment: Не храниете токен в сторадже. Безопасно в куках.

Comment: считаю что контентом лучше управлять на стороне бэка в данном случае php, куки как напиал выше doox911 наиболее оптимальный вариант, все должно получиться

Answer (score 0):

С форм входа/регистрации на VueJS отправляете на бакэнд данные (email, логин, пароль и прочее). Затем проводите валидацию данных и проверку на соответствие данным в вашей бд. Если пользователя нет, создаете и помечаете, что это обычный пользователь. Например, делаете обычную колонку group_id (1 пользователь, 2 админ) или role (admin, user).

Список групп можно для удобства хранить в какой-нибудь отдельной таблице (user_role: id, name, role и т.п.) и сделать управление ими через админку (смотреть в сторону ACL/RBAC). Затем если пользователь при входе указал верные email/пароль, авторизуете его, записывая сессию. Для хранения пароля используйте методы хеширования, например bcrypt. Для защиты конкретных маршрутов используйте middleware, где проверяйте, что пользователь состоит в конкретной группе и может получать данные.

Если для этих целей используете jwt, создаете пользователю аккаунт, проверяете введенные им при входе данные. Если все правильно, то возвращаете токен. Затем используете токен для аутентификации в последующих запросах пользователя, сам токен храните в cookie.

В качестве готовых примеров, можно взять как раз тот же [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication) (там все это есть из коробки, кроме групп, но это через дополнительные пакеты) или [Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html) (немного сложней).